# Combinatorial problem with $12$ unique cards

Tags: combinatorics

The problem is "how many ways can we distribute $12$ unique cards to $4$ persons with every person receiving at least $1$ card"

Without the requirement that everyone getting at least $1$, it would be $4^{12}$, and my initial thought was that with the req. It would be $_nP_r(12,4)\times 4^8$ but that's way too high, looks like I need to divide with some permutations that's already accounted for..

Please help!

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each admissible allocation is a surjective map $f:\>[12]\to[4]$. Such maps are counted by the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). To be precise: The number of surjective maps $f:\>[n]\to[k]$ is given by $k!\, S(n,k)$. There are recursions and tables for these numbers, but no closed formula in terms of factorials etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this directly.
First you can consider the number of way to give 12 cards to 4 players with every player having at least one card and then multiply by the number of permutation of the cards (that is $12!$).

Let $n_i$ be the number of cards of the $i^th$ player. You can have $$1\leq n_1\leq 9$$ because you have to keep at least $3$ cards for the other players. Then, for the second player, it comes
$$1\leq n_2\leq 10-n_1.$$
Finally for the third we have $$1\leq n_3 \leq 11-n_1-n_2.$$
Note that for the fourth player, his number of cards is fixed by the previous three.
In total, we have 
$$\sum_{n_1=1}^9(10-n_1)\left(\sum_{n_2=1}^{10-n_1}(11-n_1-n_2)\right)=\sum_{n_1=1}^9(10-n_1)\left((10-n_1)(11-n_1)-\sum_{n_2=1}^{10-n_1}n_2\right).$$
I let you finish the computation (and don't forget to multiply your result by $12!$).

Answer (score 0):

As you observed, without restrictions, the $12$ cards can be distributed to $4$ people in $4^{12}$ ways.  From these, we must exclude those distributions in which fewer than four people receive a card.

There are $\binom{4}{1}$ ways to exclude one person from receiving a card and $3^{12}$ ways to distribute the cards among the remaining three people.  Hence, there are $\binom{4}{1}3^{12}$ ways to exclude one person from receiving the cards.

However, if we subtract $\binom{4}{1}3^{12}$ from $4^{12}$, we will have subtracted too much since we will have subtracted those distributions in which two people do not receive a card twice, once for each way of designating one of those people as the person who does not receive a card.  Since we only want to exclude them once, we must add such distributions back.

There are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to exclude two people from receiving a card and $2^{12}$ ways to distribute the cards among the remaining two people.  Thus, there are $\binom{4}{2}2^{12}$ ways to distribute the cards so that two people are excluded from receiving a card.

However, when we subtract distributions in which one person does not receive a card and then add distributions in which two people do not receive a card, we first subtract distributions in which three people do not receive a card three times, once for each of the three ways of designating one of those three people as the person who does not receive a card, and then add them three times, once for each of the $\binom{3}{2}$ ways of designating two of those three people as the people who do not receive a card.  Consequently, we have not excluded such distributions at all.  Therefore, we need to subtract them.

There are $\binom{4}{3}$ ways to exclude three people from receiving a card and one way to give the remaining person all the cards.

Hence, by the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), there are 
$$4^{12} - \binom{4}{1}3^{12} + \binom{4}{2}2^{12} - \binom{4}{3}1^{12}$$
ways to distribute the $12$ cards to four people so that each person receives at least one card.